# Using colors from JSON data in D3 Bullet Chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to d3js and am missing something fundamental here.

In my JSON data, I've added a color element, barColor (to the second set of values):

```
[ {"title":"AMER Revenue","subtitle":"703 US$, in thousands","ranges":[840,945,1200],"measures":[703],"markers":[1050]}, {"title":"AMER COGS","subtitle":"587 US$, in thousands","ranges":[1200,832.5,740],"measures":[587],"markers":[925],"barColor":["red"]} ]
```

The JSON barColor data is being read correctly as I can use it in a variety of contexts, just not where I want.

Here's what I've got (complete with other successful tests commented out):

```
/* Select the bars and use the color from the json data */
  d3.selectAll(".bullet .measure.s0")
      //.style("fill", "red"); //This works. All .measure.s0 bars set to red.
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.barColor; }); //Why doesn't this work?
```

Specifically, it's the **d3.selectAll(".bullet .measure.s0").style("fill", function(d) { return d.barColor; });** that isn't working the way I expect. That is, I expect d.barColor to change the fill of measure.s0 to red.

I've spent quite a bit of time reading and searching, but seem to be stuck.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `.style` in this instance. Use `.attr` instead since `barColor` is already defined in the JSON data.

To fix it, try changing this:

`.style("fill", function(d) { return d.barColor; });`

To this:

`.attr("style", function(d) { return d.barColor; });`

I'm still somewhat new to d3 myself, so you might have to tweak that some, but hopefully it will put you on the right track.

Comment: @user2679918 Did this work for you? If not, let me know and we can troubleshoot some more.